# monacaのonsenui のrangeタグの連動

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, angularjs

angularjs と　onsenui のrangeタグを使ってコントローラと連動させようとしていますが、抜粋しますと、html側で

```
<input type="range" class="range" max=100 ng-model="playtime" ng-change="rangeChange()">
```

と書いて、コントローラ側で

```
$scope.rangeChange = function() {
    console.log($scope.playtime);
}
```

と書いて実行させると、最初の１回はrangeタグを操作するとconsole.logに出力されるのですが、２回め以降が反応なしです。
２回め以降もconsole.logを変化させる場合はどうすると良いでしょうか。。

Answer (score 1):

自分が質問の意図を間違えていなければ、質問に書いてあるコードそのままで動くと思います。
もし上手く動かないのであれば、質問に書いていない部分に原因があるかもしれません。

```js
ons.bootstrap()
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.rangeChange = function() {
      console.log($scope.playtime);
    }
  })
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.0-beta/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.0-beta/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.0-beta/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.0-beta/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Main</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <p style="padding-top: 80px; color: #999; text-align: center">Main Page Contents</p>
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <input type="range" class="range" max=100 ng-model="playtime" ng-change="rangeChange()">
    <br /><br />
    <span style="font-weight:bold">{{playtime}}</span>
  </div>
</body>
```